# CSS Right Side Overflows Left Side

Tags: html, css

I'm outputting a list of file names with total views (tally) beside them.

I'm trying to get the tally to overflow the file name.

..So with a file / tally list like:

```
ejs-2015-participants-list 125,000
koh-hammertown-pics 20
slaughterhouse-co-summer-run 100
```

..I'm trying to get the result of:

```
ejs-2015-participan...125,000
koh-hammertown-pics        20
slaughterhouse-co-summe...100
```

The HTML / CSS (html5 / css3) has a structure like:

```
<style>
 .box {width:200px;}
 .box span {float:left;}
 .box div {float:right;}
</style>
<div class="box">
 <span>ejs-2015-participants-list</span><div>125,000</div>
 <span>koh-hammertown-pics</span><div>20</div>
 <span>slaughterhouse-co-summer-run</span><div>100</div>
</div>
```

I'm not particular about the elements used other than 'box' is repeated so it needs to be a class. If the structure won't work or you'd rather use another selector in your example, feel free. The solution does need to validate and work in consortium compliant browsers (not worried about IE).

I've tried various inline and block level elements with various style including:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Nothings working though - any ideas?

Comment: You know, you're allowed to use tables for tabular data.

Comment: @MikeRobinson - I didn't think of that, and don't know how to get a td to overflow the left side.. Can you give an example please?

Comment: There, leveled you out ;)

Comment: Thank you sir, sorry to of assumed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tables would make the left side the same length for all rows.

You can totally get the effect you're looking for using flexbox (and for broader browser support fall back to a table solution). The idea here is that the price is the full width of its text, say "$500", and the rest of the space is filled by the item name, which has the three rules `text-oveflow`, `overflow`, and `white-space` that you mentioned.

Codepen:
http://codepen.io/tholex/pen/wKQPEV

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="name">Delicious Bagels</div>
  <div class="price">$500</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.name {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.price {}
```

Comment: Yes!! That's exactly what I was looking for! I didn't know how to describe it, and I'd never heard of flex/flex-grow... Thank you!

Comment: If you want to learn more about flexbox, check out https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Definitely better than my answer. Dig it.

Answer (score 1):

So I used a table for this, since it helps with alignment of the data and is semantically correct. No need to mess with floats.

The trick is really in the CSS. Set a max width, text-overflow of ellipsis, and don't allow word break. The actual ellipsis trick doesn't need to be in a table - any block level element can handle it.

Here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVQYWJ

**CSS**

```
.table td {
    text-align: right;
}

.table th {
    text-align: left;

}

.table th {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>ejs-2015-participants-list</th>
        <td>125,000</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>koh-hammertown-pics</th>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>slaughterhouse-co-summer-run</th>
        <td>100</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I get the same effect as with divs - the left side is chopped based on width vs left side overflows right based on varying width (if that makes sense).

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is your `.box` is too small to contain the div so it drops down. One solution is to make it wider but you have other problems.

Your span is an inline element while the div is block level. I don't know why you do it that way but you should probably contain those two inside their own div so one doesn't overflow into the other.

```
<div class="box">
    <div>
        <span> stuff </span><div>125,000</div>
    </div>
    ...
```

Though it seems to me you should turn the div with the number into a span also. Then everything is inline.

Comment: My question states any element can be used. The width isn't the issue, nothing is 'dropping down' (they float left and right).

Comment: @user3925824 It does drop down for me due to the width in both chrome and Firefox